# Approaches to Sometimes Loading Images Into RecyclerView Layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` that loads a list of posts from an array. Sometimes the posts will have an image URL and I would like to show the image in the `ViewHolder` if it has one. I would really like to reuse the same layout file so that changes are easy to make and post containers look identical. What is the best approach to do this? I have three solutions in mind.

1. Create an `ImageView` in the `ViewHolder`'s layout file with a height of 0dp and change the height if an image needs to be loaded.
2. Create a separate layout file for image posts and use that whenever an image needs to be loaded. I don't like this because if I make a change to other post types I also have to change the image posts so they look the same.
3. Create an `ImageView` programatically and use `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` to adjust constraints. I dont like this because it seems like it would break easily and be difficult to fix.

Are there more solutions that are better than the ones I listed?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the `ImageView` in your xml file as height and width `wrap_content`. It shows image when image available otherwise it is not visible.
2. Check if String url is not null set imageviews visibility is `android:visibility="visible"`. When String url is null set `ImageView` visibility is `android:visibility="gone"`.